# Android studio - stay connected to a bluetooth socket at all times

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I am building an Android app that uses Bluetooth.
For a couple of weeks now I've been trying to create service that could provide Bluetooth connection to a socket at all times, but nothing worked for me.
The goal: Bluetooth service that is connected even if the app is closed.
I've tried:
 - Bound service
 - Singleton service
 - Shared class

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Please remove all references to Android Studio. It has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Please do check Foreground Services and keep in mind that newer Android versions are making more strictness on how much they allow such services to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run service all the time unless you use foreground notification, [check here](https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/), if it is visible then your service is running even the app is killed